# Probability that two people each are selected from each of two groups

Tags: probability

I am having problems with this task:

> There is a group of 18 people, 9 in group A and 9 in group B. 4 of them will stay behind to clean. They are chosen at random. What is the probability of two from each group staying behind?

I assume that that once on person is selected there will be 17, 16, 15 in total.

I have attempted $\frac{18!}{2!}\times \frac{18!}{2!}$, but I still get the wrong answer.  I also tried using the $^nP_r$ and $^nC_r$ to solve this on my Casio calculator. What would be the correct manner to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The required selections of $2$ from each group are $\binom92\binom92$

The unrestricted selections are $\binom{18}4$

Can you proceed now ?

Comment: So when two from each group stay behind the answer will be 3/24310?

Comment: Compute properly, even a sanity check should tell you that the answer is wrong.

Comment: I did it again and got 0.423529412. Seems more reasonable :) Thank you.

Comment: @Emil: Good work. Glad to be of help !  :)